# I removed my GUI and now I can't install another one

Tags: gui, desktop-environments

It's simple, I was using KDE (worst choice of my life) and decided to remove it. Then I did it, and now I'm unable to install another one. I'm using ubuntu 16.04

I'm trying to reinstall unity, but when I try:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

I got the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested and impossible situations or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming 

The following information may be helpful: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies: ubuntu-desktop :

Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed 

Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pktcompat but it is not going to be installed 

Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Comment: Which one do you want to install? Why are you unable to install it (are you getting an error message? What does it say? Or are you just not sure of the right command?) More details would be helpful.

Comment: sure, just hold on a bit

Comment: I'm trying to reinstall unity, but when I try to `sudo apt-get --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` i got the following:

`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested and impossible situations or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required... etc`
The following packages have unmet dependencies: ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but not going to be installed
Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pktcompat not going to be installed
Recommends: unity-webapps-common not goint to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: @innis please [edit] your question to include the extra information - instead of adding it in the comments section

Comment: @steeldriver done

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @NickWeinberg 16.04

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`, then try your original command again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "reinstall" a package that isn't installed.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or you can

```
sudo tasksel
```

to select a desktop environment to install.